# How to create a view to display a block of referenced nodes?

Tags: 7, views, entities, nodes

I have a node type, called "policy", that has a bunch of CCK fields, including a Node Reference type.  This is configured to reference an unlimited number of nodes.

When the nodes are viewed, the list of referenced nodes appear at the bottom of the content.  Ideally, I'd like to put these in a block on the side of the content.

I've tried writing a view that accepts an NID as an argument and displays the CCK field.  This works in the Views configuration preview (displays expected results), but when I put this block on the side bar, and view a node, I do not see any results at all.

I do not have a relationship specified in the view - I'm not really clear on if I need to use it or not.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When configuring the argument for the block, set it to "Provide a default argument", and configure that to use the nid of the node being viewed.